# Android Studio R not linking for seemingly no reason

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, r.java-file

When I am working in a new project, occasionally I will run into an issue where R.(insert rest of resource path)
Will just stop working.  The only work around I have found is to copy the files and place them in a new project.  What could possibly cause R not to be found for onCreate?

Comment: Try to clean your project. Go to **AndroidStudio > build > clean Peroject**

Answer (score 0):

try this: Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Message box appears, click on Invalidate and Restart.